# WSO2EI Multiple transportReceivers

Tags: wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-esb

Did anyone tried to have WSOESB works by listening to more than the default two ports (8280 and 8243)??

By default, all proxy services will be exposed using these two ports, but for high-performance, you might need to have more listeners on the ESB on approximately 15-20 ports.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can configure transport receivers in `<EI_HOME>/conf/Axis2/axis2.xml` file.

See https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI611/Multi-HTTPS+Transport for an example.

However, I don't think you need multiple listeners just for the performance because even if you have a single listener, each request will be assigned to a separate thread.

Comment: Thanks .. figured I have to run another instance if I want to have more ports for listening .. That would be only for excess amount of requests in distributed environment.